# PasswordChangeDoneView dose not redirect to " change password done page"

Tags: python, django, class

In class base view "django" I have a problem , after post email with "PasswordResetView" the django go to login page but it must show me "PasswordChangeDoneView"

views:

```
class UserPassReset(PasswordResetView):
    template_name = 'accounts/password_reset_form.html'
    success_url   = reverse_lazy('accounts:PasswordChangeDone')
    #success_url = 'done'
    email_template_name = 'accounts/password_reset_email.html'


class PasswordChangeDone( PasswordChangeDoneView):
    template_name='accounts/password_reset_done.html'
```

urls:

```
 path('login/', views.UserLogin.as_view() , name='UserLogin'),
 path('passreset/', views.UserPassReset.as_view() , name='UserPassReset'),
 path('passreset/done', views.PasswordChangeDone.as_view(), name='PasswordChangeDone'),
```

HTML reset password:

```
{% block content %}
    <h3>Enter Email </h3>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: if you don't mind can you upvote my answer too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused between password change & password reset Views.

This view is used when you redirect after changing password:

```
PasswordChangeDoneView
```

And this view is used when you redirect after reseting password:

```
PasswordResetCompleteView
```

This is built-in view so you have to import it & then use it directly in urls.py like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
    path('passreset/done', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view
    (template_name='accounts/password_reset_done.html'), name='passreset_done'),
```